# Linq OrderBy (or something like it) with IQueryable

Tags: asp.net, linq

I can't seem to find a solution to ordering a database using a filter. When I return submissions, it returns the database before it's filtered out. So instead of the var submissions = Biz.Data.AllItems.LoadNotDeleted() line where the database gets filtered, the return submissions just returns the entire result. I've tried different versions of return submissions = submissions.(something) to filter the list but I am not getting any available options.

```
public IQueryable<Biz.Data.AllItems> items_GetData()
{
   var submissions = Biz.Data.AllItems.LoadNotDeleted().Where(x => 
   x.itemOne != null && 
   x.itemTwo != null && 
   x.itemThree != null));
   var filter = new Biz.Data.AllItemsFilter();

        var fileType = ddlFileType.SelectedValue;
        var session = ddlSession.SelectedValue;


        filter.IsDeleted = false;
        filter.IsCancelled = false;
        filter.IsAbstractSubmission = true;

        switch (fileType)
        {
            case "Abstract":
                filter.FilterExpression = x => x.AbstractUserUploadId.HasValue;
                break;
            case "Poster":
                filter.FilterExpression = x => x.PosterUserUploadId.HasValue;
                break;
            case "Audio":
                filter.FilterExpression = x => x.AudioUserUploadId.HasValue;
                break;
            case "Transcript":
                filter.FilterExpression = x => x.TranscriptUserUploadId.HasValue;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (session != "All")
        {
            filter.AbstractTopic.MatchType = Dms.Framework.EntityFramework.Match.Exact;
            filter.AbstractTopic.Value = session;
        }
   return submissions = Biz.Data.AllItems.Load(filter).OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName);
}
```

LoadNotDeleted =

```
    public static DbQuery<Registration> LoadNotDeleted()
    {
        var filter = new RegistrationFilter();
        filter.IsDeleted = false;
        return Load(filter, Int32.MaxValue, 0, ConferenceEventsEntities.Current);
    }
```

Load =

```
    public static DbQuery<Registration> Load(RegistrationFilter filter)
    {
        return Load(filter, Int32.MaxValue, 0, ConferenceEventsEntities.Current);
    }
```

Comment: Yes bad phrasing, not a list a database table

Comment: I have added it

Comment: To explain why you get the wrong submission: `string GetFoo(){ string foo = "foo";     return foo = "bah";  }` Result will be "bah" because you assign it to the variable so the first assignment is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your problem could just be solved by completely removing those "AllData" parts:

```
var submissions = Biz.Data
                     .AllItems
                     .LoadNotDeleted()
                     .Where(x => x.itemOne != null && x.itemTwo != null && x.itemThree != null)
                     .OrderBy(x => x.LastName)
                     .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName);

return submissions;
```

If that was not what you meant, you will need to elaborate.

Comment: There is a var filter that needs to be added to filter based on the user filter

Comment: What type is it? i can see it's an "AllItemsFilter" by name but that does not make sense since that would not filter anything...

Comment: So what do the "LoadNotDeleted" and "Load(filter)" methods do?